# Can't get update statement in SQL Server to work

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to execute this SQL Update statement and it's not working.  Does anyone know why ?

```
update dbo.EBSTable 
set CommandField = replace(CommandField, '%APPL.mbm_aging_file', '%APPL.mbm_aging_file)') 
where Command like '[%]APPL.mbm_aging_file'
```

Basically, I'm just trying to add a ")" to the end of the data appearing in the `CommandField` field where the value is `%APPL.mbm_aging_file` (The "%" actually appears in the data).

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: After I execute the Update statement, I do a query to look at the data and the ")" isn't appearing at the end of the data.

Comment: Never seen brackets put around a `%` before. Does removing them have any effect? If you want to include the `%` symbol as part of your `like` clause, you will have to add an additional `%`... `where Command like '%\%APPL.mbm_aging_file' ESCAPE '\'`

Comment: @Samcd - That is a valid way of escaping the `%` but probably the OP needs an additional `%` one or both sides as otherwise they might as well use `=`

Answer (score 1):

```
update dbo.EBSTable 
set CommandField = '%APPL.mbm_aging_file' + ')' -- or set CommandField = '%APPL.mbm_aging_file)'
where Command = '%APPL.mbm_aging_file'
```

You can do this, as you only need to add `)` at the end only for this specific case.

Comment: `'%APPL.mbm_aging_file' + ')'` can be simplified to `'%APPL.mbm_aging_file)'`

Comment: @MartinSmith..totally missed that :)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered my where clause was inadequate (like me with SQL).  It should read

`update dbo.EBSTable set CommandField = replace(CommandField, '%APPL.mbm_aging_file', '%APPL.mbm_aging_file)') where Command like '%[%]APPL.mbm_aging_file%'`

That statement worked.

Comment: `_` is also a wildcard character so you could use `where Command like '%[%]APPL.mbm[_]aging[_]file%'` to be really correct.